# Retag: sunsolaris10 → solaris-10, sunsolaris → solaris

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I suggest adding `sunsolaris10` as an synonym to `solaris-10`.

As well, add `sunsolaris` as an synonym to `solaris`.

The bare name is more correct.

Comment: "Acronym"?  Meanst thou "synonym"?

Comment: *pffffffftfff!*

Comment: x3 `solaris10` retaged to `solaris-10`. `Solaris` is probably a more widespread usage as the correct name is now `Oracle Solaris`.

Comment: x6 sunsolaris retaged to solaris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This retagging has been completed.